# PHP table creation from multiple SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to create PHP table from multiple table from SQL. I am unable to print the information for a record from multiple database table in one row.

Code:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($info)){

   foreach($field as $query){
     echo "<td>" . $row[$query] . "</td>" ;     

   }

echo "<tr>";
 }



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($standing)){

foreach($field as $query){
  echo "<td>" . $row[$query] . "</td>" ;
  }

}
```

Example my login is NT882, and I have information in "info" and "standing" table, this code prints all the information from "info" table, and then from next line prints the information from "standing" table.

I want to print first 4 columns from "info" table, and next 2 columns from "standing" table in that particular row.

Comment: what result of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

If its, about HTML Table generation from PHP. then try this way.

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($info)){
   echo "<tr>"; 
   //get fields to $fields
   foreach($field as $query){
     echo "<td>" . $row[$query] . "</td>" ;     
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($standing)){
    echo "<tr>";
   //get fields to $fields
    foreach($field as $query){
        echo "<td>" . $row[$query] . "</td>" ;
    }
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```